# How to add text to scikit-learn's confusion matrix?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I wish to add on text to each cell of a confusion matrix object from scikit-learn. More specifically, I wish to put True Positive in the top left cell, False Positive in the top right cell etc. Is there a easy to way to do so, or do I have to use annotate and specify the coordinates?

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.tight_layout

cm_benign = metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions(
    y_true, y_pred, ax=ax1, labels=["benign", "malignant"], colorbar=False
)
ax1.set_title("Confusion Matrix (Benign as +)")
cm_malignant = metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions(
    y_true, y_pred, ax=ax2, labels=["malignant", "benign"], colorbar=False
)
ax2.set_title("Confusion Matrix (Malignant as +)")
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.8)
plt.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use seaborn to put the labels on your figure. You may also be able to use the `display_labels` parameter along with `labels` as you currently have, I'm not sure if it'll work as well since the list of labels wouldn't be the same, even for the same confusion matrix.

```
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

x_labels = ["False Positive", "False Negative"]
y_labels = ["True Positive", "True Negative"]
cm = confusion_matrix(x, y)
heatmap = sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='d', xticklabels=x_labels, yticklabels=y_labels)
figure = heatmap.get_figure()
# show or save figure
plt.close(cm)
```